# Drawing an image in its full size in a canvas works only on the second try in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, filereader

I'm trying to get images from users and draw in them stuff. But I'm getting strange behaviour in MF to only show the image in its full size in a canvas.
I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <input type="file" id="input">
  <div id="main"></div>
  <script>
   document.getElementById('input').onchange = function() {
    var file_reader = new FileReader();
    file_reader.onload = function() {
     var img = new Image();
     img.src = file_reader.result;

     var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
     canvas.width = img.width;
     canvas.height = img.height;

     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height)

     document.getElementById('main').appendChild(canvas)
    }
    file_reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('input').files[0])
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome and Opera everything works fine, but in Mozilla Firefox when I choose an image nothing happens, the added canvas has width 0 and height 0. Then if I reselect it again it'll show up, and thus for each image, I have to select it once, nothing happens, and then on the second, third etc. times everything works fine.
 Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd give a try to draw the image on the canvas in the img.onload callback.